# Sublime User Keybindings Error

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-14.04, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

I am running sublime text 3 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I added the following line to the user key bindings:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+s"], "command": "save_all" }
```

Following this forum: [Sublime Save All](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5946)

Now, when I start sublime, I get the following error that pops up:

> Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:7:2

This error appears whether the additional keybinding is present or removed, or if there's a comma after the final } or not. At this point, figuring out a way to remove the pop up is just as good as making it work. Any ideas on how to help?

---

EDIT:
As requested, my complete user keybindings file:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+s"], "command": "save_all" }
]
```

Comment: Please provide your complete keybininds file, especially the line before and after the new one.

Comment: @mpy I added the complete file in the question.

Comment: Ah, the error says error parsing _preferences.sublime-settings_ (line 7). It's not the keybindings file (which even has not seven lines).

Comment: There's the error! sloppy mistake on my end

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives you a good hint, where to look for the error:

> Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in Packages/User/**Preferences.sublime-settings:7**:2

It gives you the file, where the error occurs (*Preferences.sublime-settings*) and the line number *7*. Very often such an error occurs, if you forget the line separator (*comma*) in the line before, so in this example in line 6.